# Converting a file to array with FS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filestream

I have a simple "en.txt"

```
"TITLE"     => "Amazing title of my page"
"COPYRIGHT" => "Copyright my site"
"BLABLA"    => "A amazing sentence"
```

And I would like convert this in array for nodeJS with FS.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what did you try? maybe you should use google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read the file data using the [fs.readFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) method. Once you have the file data in a variable, you can convert it into an array using the following regular expression:

```
var regex = /"([^"]+)"\s*=>\s*"([^"]+)/g;
var match, results = {};

while((match = regex.exec(fileData)) !== null){
    results[match[1]] = match[2];
}

console.log(results); // contains js array of data
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKnqc/).